# What conditions cause a web browser to display the "Page Expired" message?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I assumed that sending a page out with an expiry (a la)...

```
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

...would mean that if the user hit the back button they would see the "Page Expired" message.  It does not seem to work that way.  I found that using the back button would simply show the **old** (IMO expired) page.  In fact in experimenting with different combinations of caching/not caching and expiry times I **NEVER** managed to get the "Page Expired" message out of the browser.

What conditions provoke that message?

Server Environment ASP .Net.  I've only tested in IE8 - I'm assuming that other browsers are consistent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set these additional response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Pragma: no-cache
```

However, I don't think there's any reliable way to force all browsers to not reload a page from history.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is the message that are displayed when trying to reload/refresh (or back) a page that you have posted data to (with a POST request in oppose to a GET), therefor, since the POST-data might be "old" information, you recieve that warning.

Comment: Thanks, but no.  I think that is the message that says "To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted...".  That's not what I'm thinking of.  I believe (am I just wrong here?) that there is a message claiming that the page has expired.  I seem unable to provoke that message so I could just be barking up the wrong tree.